# Failure when uploading large images in Livewire 2

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am using a livewire component to upload images from a file input. It is working in general, however I am facing an issue. Whenever a user uploads an image that is bigger than the php `upload_max_filesize` (Currently set to 2M) - the upload silently fails with no error feedback.

I have explicitly set the validation max filesize in the livewire config as seen below.

Am I missing something or do I need to write some client side validation?

```
<input
    x-ref="imageUpload"
    id="imageUpload"
    class="hidden"
    type="file"
    multiple
    wire:model="images"
    />

@if($errors->any())
    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}
@endif

@foreach ($images as $image)
    <img src="{{ $image->temporaryUrl() }}" />               
@endforeach
```

Livewire Config:

```
'temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => null,       
        'rules' => ['required', 'image', 'file', 'max:2048'], 
        'directory' => null,   
        'middleware' => null, 
        'preview_mimes' => [   
            'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
            'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
            'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
        ],
        'max_upload_time' => 5,
    ],
```